# Calculating the order of poles of $\frac{\sin(3z)}{z^2}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, residue-calculus

I have the function $f(z)=\frac{\sin(3z)}{z^2}$ and want to calculate the order of the poles.

If we look at $\frac{1}{f}=0$ we have that $\frac{z^2}{\sin(3z)}=0$ and hence I would assume the pole would be at $z_0=0$ and it has order 2. However, Wolfram says the order is 1?

The order is obviously equal to 1, as when I calculate the residue, I have the Laurent series as
$$f(z)=\frac{3}{z}-\frac{9}{2}z+\frac{81}{40}z^3-\dots$$
and the residue is 3. And this can also be calculated  $$\lim_{z\to 0}(z)\frac{\sin(3z)}{z^2}=\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{\sin(3z)}{z}=3$$. However this method only works for simple poles, so the order must be 1.

I'm just trying to figure how we can calculate the order of the poles of the function directly as 1 instead of 2?

Answer (score 1):

The order of a pole is the greatest positive integer $m$ for which $a_{-m}\neq 0$ in the Laurent series, so after you calculate the Laurent series you're done; simply observe $a_{-1}\neq 0$ yet $a_{k}=0$ for $k\leq -2$.

Here's a way to "see" the order of a pole at a glance. If $f$ and $g$ are analytic in a disk about $z_0$, and $f$ and $g$ have zeroes of order $n$ and $m$ at $z_0$ respectively, then $f/g$ has a removable singularity at $z_0$ when $n\geq m$, and a pole at $z_0$ of order $m-n$ otherwise. This is not too hard to show from the definitions. In this case, $\sin(3z)$ has an order $1$ zero at $z=0$ while $z^2$ has an order $2$ zero at $z=0$. Thus $\sin(3z)/z^2$ has a simple pole at $z=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Your Laurent series shows you the order of the pole correctly. Since it "starts" at the $z^{-1}$-term, i.e. does not have any terms of more negative powers of $z$, the order is $1$.